# Conditional Formatting - change default view in Rules Manager?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Often times I edit some rules, and "Ok out", only to realize I did it for the selection, not sheet.

When opening conditional formatting, via "Manage Rules", is there a way to have Excel default to show the rules for `This Worksheet` instead of `Current Selection`?

To be clear, I'm not asking for precedence of the rules, but rather which rules *show* by default.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if there is Excel-only solution. Are you fine with installing 3rd-party helper tool to do that? (Or at least with learning how to reach the result?)

Comment: @miroxlav hmmm if that's the only way. Could you do it with VBA? I tried looking but couldn't find a way via macro or VBA.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but I have reasons to think it is not possible via VBA. Yet in Excel 2013 I tried controlling this conditional formatting using VBA and found that not all things which can be done in user interface have their equivalent methods in VBA. Maybe they added something in Excel 2016, but if I can guess, I doubt about it. From my findings, there's no VBA way, although I can be wrong.

Comment: @miroxlav I believe you're right. From everything I know about VBA, this isn't possible (...if it is I bet it would be closer  to a "hack" than a proper way to do it).

Comment: This is not the only time where VBA isn't 1:1 with user interface. So just let me know whether workaround shown in the answer practically helped you to start the Rules Manager with changed default view.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with Excel 2013 I believe that this functionality is not accessible via VBA. However, you can achieve it by this [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) macro which I bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as part of the example:

```
;--------------------------------- header with some global settings
SendMode Input
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

;--------------------------------- Hotkeys/Excel only
#IfWinActive - Excel$ ; only in windows contatining "- Excel" in title
^+c::Send !od{Down 2}{Enter}+{Tab 3}
#IfWinActive
```

It basically sends series of keystrokes to achieve expected effect. If something does not work for you (for example, if you have other than English version of Excel, so <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> is not opening **Conditional Formatting** window, replay the above key sequence manually and you will be easily able to find what needs fixing. If you are not familiar with AHK, the seqence is: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, 3×(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

AutoHotKey is your friend in many situations where authors of applications did not implement something.

Edit:

1. I changed keyboard shortcut to unused one.
2. I missed the functionality, too, so thank you for motivating me to solve this. Also it is more convenient to have the dialog at single keyboard shortcut instead of the default sequential one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - it looks promising, but I'm assuming there's no real way to do it without a 3rd party program/software?

Comment: @BruceWayne – perhaps by getting inspired by the above key sequence, but sending it directly from the VBA using [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-sendkeys-method-excel) method?

Comment: yeah good call, I've thought about that too. I guess I'd have to macro the whole key sequence including calling conditional formatting.